# I am not able to call Lockbox 3 AES Encryption written in Delphi from C#

Tags: c#, delphi

I have written a function to encrypt a string in Delphi 10. It all works fine which I have the same function in Winform and the result is displayed in the Memo field, however, when I call the function from C#, I get an error
When i run this call Encrypt function from C# I get "Parameter not found" Which is from the exception in Delphi.

Can someone help here?

```
function Encrypt(str: PWideChar; len: Integer): Boolean; stdcall;
 begin
  try
   eString := AES128_Encrypt('Test','TestPassword');
   PwValue := PWideChar(eString);
    StrLCopy(str, PwValue, len);
    Result := true;
  except
    On E: Exception do
    begin
    PwValue := PWideChar(E.Message);
    StrLCopy(str, PwValue, len);
    end;
  end;

end;

function AES128_Encrypt(Value, Password: string): string; stdcall;
var
  hCProv: HCRYPTPROV;
  hKey: HCRYPTKEY;
  lul_datalen: Integer;
  lul_buflen: Integer;
  Buffer: TBytes;
begin
  Assert(Password <> '');
  if (Value = '') then
    Result := ''
  else begin
    hCProv := __CryptAcquireContext(PROV_RSA_AES);
    try
      hKey := __AES128_DeriveKeyFromPassword(hCProv, Password);
      try
        // allocate buffer space
        lul_datalen := Length(Value) * SizeOf(Char);
        Buffer := TEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Value + '        ');
        lul_buflen := Length(Buffer);
        // encrypt to buffer
        Win32Check(CryptEncrypt(hKey, 0, True, 0, @Buffer[0], lul_datalen, lul_buflen));
        SetLength(Buffer, lul_datalen);
        // base 64 result
        Result := Base64_Encode(Buffer);
      finally
        CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
      end;
    finally
      CryptReleaseContext(hCProv, 0);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Calling it like

```
eString := AES128_Encrypt('ii', 'o3ew232we22o');
```

C# Code

```
 [DllImport(@"<Path of dll>", EntryPoint = "Enrypt", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool Enrypt(StringBuilder sb, int len);

public static string Encrypt()
{
    try
    {
      StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(256);
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
      bool result =  Encrypt(str, str.Capacity);
    
      if (result)
      {
          return str.ToString();
       }
    }            
 catch (Exception ex1)
 {
    MessageBox.Show(ex1.ToString());
 }
    
 return "";
 }
```

Comment: where is the c# code?

Comment: posted the complete code

Comment: 2 remarks, 1) mark your delphi encryption routine as stdcall, if you don't specify the calling convention it will be cdecl by default. 2) Use Widestring on the delphi side and marshal as BSTR on the C#. Pwidechar and stringbuilder are not compatible

Comment: I marked the function as stdcall (pls see updated code). I am not getting the second comment. If i replace my AES128_Encrypt('Test','TestPassword') with 'some junk i wanted to return' it just works fine

Comment: Delphi Pwidechar can not be marshalled as a c# string builder, it is as simple as that.

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting it, can you suggest me what I need to change here

Comment: Delphi: `function Encrypt(var str: Widestring): Boolean; stdcall;`

Comment: when i change this the below line is failing StrLCopy(str, PwValue, len);

Comment: You don't need that, just remove all pchar related code...

Comment: See the problem is function Encrypt is not even called from C#, what i am doing is within Delphi, the function is called and stores some string after encryption and this all works fine with WinVCF project, but i want to do this operation from C# and dont want to return any thing back to C#. This is not working. Let me know if it makes sense